# Ubuntu install saying not enough disk space

Tags: boot, partitioning, acpi, busybox

I have a Dell XPS which had Ubuntu on it but it started playing up so booted from USB in the hope to install a fresh version but I now get the message saying

> You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu.

When I do fdisk I get the following

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1553670144 bytes, 3034512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.2 GiB, 7747397632 bytes, 15131636 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x38f8fce6

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 15131635 15129588  7.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Disk usage analyzer also doesn't recognise the drive on the laptop. When I try and boot into the laptop I get a load of varios errors before being dumped into BusyBox

Any suggestions on how to wipe it all and start from fresh? The BIOS seems to recognise it fine

When switching on the laptop (without USB), a screen about ACPI errors comes up but goes quickly into a Ubuntu loading screen (with 5 dots under the logo). After a few mins I get thrown into busybox (can't upload screenshots) but a few errors about:

ACPI error: Method parse/execution failed

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: When switching on the laptop (without USB), a screen about ACPI errors comes up but goes quickly into a Ubuntu loading screen (with 5 dots under the logo). After a few mins I get thrown into busybox (will edit original)

Comment: in grub press "E" to edit the launch command. Change "quiet splash" to "no-splash" then boot. this will show the booting process and the error occuring. the ACPI errors are common with the new kernels, they can be ignored

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu USB, start `Disks`, select the hard disk in the left pane, click on the "hamburger" icon, select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data. Run the tests. Report back.

Comment: @ravery failed to connect to lvmetad happens quite a lot. heynnema will try that next

Comment: @heynnema the disk isn't shown. Only the USB and a loop device. The drive shows in BIOS though.

Comment: In your BIOS, is the disk set to RAID or something else?

Comment: Under non-raid physical disks it is listed there. Status is non-raid if I go into menu below.

Comment: See if `gparted` finds the disk. Otherwise, you should check the connections at the disk, or replace the disk.

Comment: If I set boot list option to UEFI it lists my 512GB drive and my USB

Comment: Which 512G drive, internal? Do you dual-boot w/Windows?

Comment: Internal laptop drive yes. No dual boot. No data needs saving so just want to start fresh

Comment: In UEFI mode, does `Disks` or `fdisk` or `gparted` now see the drive?

Comment: No, still same as before

Comment: Time to replace the drive.

Comment: I agree with heynnema. if it was a partitioning or formating error, the drive would show as unallocated or something but it would be there

Comment: So I installed Windows on it and it's working fine. Installed Ubuntu instead after and all good. Very odd.

Answer (score 3):

We found that - as noted on [the Dell forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217080000/http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19659260) - disabling system RAID and putting the HD into AHCI mode was sufficient to solve this problem.

> Enabling AHCI mode AFTER Windows 10 installation (IDE or RAID).
>
> 1. Run Command Prompt as Admin
> 2. Invoke a Safe Mode boot with the command: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
> 3. Restart the PC and enter your BIOS during bootup.
> 4. Change from IDE to AHCI mode then Save & Exit.
> 5. Windows 10 will launch in Safe Mode.
> 6. Right click the Window icon and select to run the Command Prompt in Admin mode from among the various options.
> 7. Cancel Safe Mode booting with the command: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
> 8. Restart your PC once more and this time it will boot up normally but with AHCI mode activated.
>
> Source:
>
> [www.tenforums.com/.../15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217080000/http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html)
>
> For Windows 7/8:
>
> [superuser.com/.../switching-from-raid-to-ahci-with-windows-8](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217080000/http://superuser.com/questions/530464/switching-from-raid-to-ahci-with-windows-8)